# What is the distribution of $X'AX$ when $A$ is not necessarily a symmetric matrix?

Tags: normal-distribution, references, terminology

Assume that $X$ is a multivariate normal random variable($n$-vector) with known mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\sigma^2 I_n$.

What is the distribution of $X'AX$ when $A$ is not necessarily a symmetric matrix?

I want a reference concerning this type of random variables. Thanks!

Comment: If A isn't symmetric then the distribution isn't "nice" or useful. I doubt there are any references exploring such distributions, because it wouldn't be a rewarding exercise.

Comment: @GordonSmyth What if $A$ belongs to a certain class of matrices (e.g. tri-diagonal matrices). I do not know the name/term for such kind of researches? Are they known as 'special quasi-linear form of normal random vector' or sth like that? Of course I am not expecting any result for a general $A$. Thanks!

Comment: @GordonSmyth That is what I thought of, but is there any result that assert sth for a special class of matrices(permutation matrices, binary matrices)?

Comment: Since $x^T A x = x^T \frac{A + A^T}{2} x$ for all $x$, it shouldn't matter whether $A$ is symmetric since $x^T A x$ is equivalent to a symmetric quadratic form.

Comment: @Ben I do not think what you wrote down make sense to me...could you kindly explain a bit??

Comment: Ben has pointed out a key point that I managed to forget. This trick allows you to compute all the moments of the distribution. The exact distribution of the quadratic form will still be pretty intractable however if $A+A^T$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have that $$x^T A x = x^T (A^T)^T x = (A^T x)^T x = x^T (A^T x) = x^T A^T x,$$ making $$x^T \frac{A + A^T}{2} x = \frac{1}{2} x^T A x + \frac{1}{2} x^T A^T x = \frac{1}{2} x^T A x + \frac{1}{2} x^T A x = x^T A x.$$ Therefore your problem of $A$ not being symmetric is ameliorated since you need only study the properties of the matrix $\frac{1}{2} \left( A + A^T \right)$, which is indeed symmetric. In the theory of quadratic forms, it isn't restrictive to assume that every defining matrix is symmetric: symmetry is just a freebie!

Put the eigendecomposition $A + A^T = U D U^T$ for orthogonal $U$ and diagonal $D$. Define $y = \frac{1}{\sigma} U^T x \sim\mathcal{N}(\frac{1}{\sigma} U^T \mu, I)$. Then, we see that 
\begin{align*}
 x^T A x 
 & = x^T \frac{1}{2} (A + A^T) x \\
 & = \frac{\sigma^2}{2} y^T D y \\
 & \sim \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{\mathrm{rank}(A + A^T)} \lambda_j \chi_1^2 \left( \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \|\mu\|_2^2 \right),
\end{align*}
where $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\|\mu\|_2^2$ is the noncentrality parameter, $\{\lambda_j\}$ is the spectrum of $A +A^T$, and the $\chi^2$ random variables are independent.

Comment: Make sense and thanks a lot... I miss the point! Appreciated.